# Locate and Delete Folder(s) with Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

At work we handle people every day who wants help regarding signing on to their Online Bank from home. Some times we need the user to delete files and guiding them to do this, can be tiresome and bothersome a lot of the time, wasting upwards to 20 minutes because the user is inexperienced in computers.

We have been talking about a solution (if possible) where we let the user download a batch file that we tell them to run, which can then delete the required files for us. I ask this question here, because none of us here at work, have experience with batch files.

Personally I've played around with it from time to time but I can't really come up with a solution that fits our needs and when I search around on the net, I can't find a solution that fits either. The script would have to locate the folder automatically (if possible).

1. Is this possible?
2. Would you be able to help me accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually *mean* DOS, or do you mean the command prompt in Windows? Although similar, they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean with automatically but I'd say that your task can be accomplished using a Batch file. Try to split your task you are trying to do into parts (Like 1. Search folders 2. Ask to delete 3. Delete folders) and search just these parts on the web ;)

Comment: How would the files be identified? What is a common feature that the files have?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You got a point. I will correct it, as it's the command prompt.

Comment: @user2033427 Should just be folders. Have the same names every time.

Comment: Are they in the same place(s) every time or could they be anywhere?

Comment: @user2033427 Yes pretty much. But it's in a specific user folder, so how do I obtain the username and put it in..?

Comment: There are various environment variables like `%APPDATA%`, `%HOMEPATH%`, `%USERPROFILE%` etc that will point to the users' directory etc. Is it possible to say where the files are exactly?

Comment: @user2033427 C:\Users\<Username>\.oces2 is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple one:

```
rd /s "%USERPROFILE%\.oces2"
```

If they follow a pattern (e.g. start with .oces):

```
@echo off
cd /d "%USERPROFILE%"
for /d %%i in (.oces*) do rd /s "%%i"
pause
```

Comment: Do the folder names follow a pattern (e.g. they start with `.oces`)?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help you, I commented it so you understand what it is doing ;)

```
:: Program to remove Folders which fullfill the criterias

:: You won't see the commands in the console
@echo off

:: Go to drive C (i think you'll need application data or similar and this is 
:: on c, but if the bat is started in an other partition, it will search the 
:: one he starts in
C:
:: Go to the path in which you'll search, if you want C:\ , remove this
CD "C:\yoursearchstartpath"

:: Okay, this is the loop, it gets all folders ( /A -D  is for folders)
:: which have delMe in their name and then asks if you want to delete it
:: showing the path to make sure you don't delete sth accidentially
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /S /B /A -D *delMe*') do RD /S "%%a"

:: That the batch file is not closed automatically but shows that it's finished
set /p id="Finished, press Space to quit " %=%
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994

I created a sample batch file A.BAT. It checks if the C:\Folder\F1 exists, and removed the folder F1 if available

```
IF EXIST D:\FOLDER\F1 GOTO A
EXIT
:A
D:
DEL D:\FOLDER\F1\*.*
RMDIR F1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Added DEL *.* command to clear folder, before removing folder using RMDIR